# Fields are duplicated and have incorrect default values when validation fails in Rails 3 in form with multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I am building an application to enable users to sign up for a canoe trip. The view displays a quantity field for each possible "item" on the trip (i.e., canoe, double kayak, single kayak) through fields_for :line_items that is part of a form_for @order. I perform validation on the line item object to assure that the number entered is a positive integer.

When quantity values are entered that all pass validation, everything works as expected. However, **when a quantity value fails validation (e.g., a negative value), the resulting view displays incorrectly, and the nature of the incorrectness depends on the entered data**. If only 1 value failed validation but the other two were blank, then the incorrect value displays for all items' quantity fields, and each item is displayed only once. If 1 value failed validation, but the other 2 passed validation, then each item and its corresponding quantity field is displayed 3 times consecutively (i.e., canoe x 3, double kayak x 3, single kayak x 3) with the default quantity correct in this case. The behavior further changes in other cases, but I hope what I've described so far is enough for someone to explain to me how to fix this.

Relevant code snippets are below:

LineItem

```
...
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :order
validates :quantity, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than: -1, message: "cannot be negative"}
...
```

OrdersController

```
def new
@trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
if ! @trip.user_registered?(current_user)
  @items = Item.find_all_by_destination_specific_activity_id(@trip.destination_specific_activity.id)
  @order = Order.new
  @order.line_items.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @order }
  end
else
  @order = Order.find_by_user_id_and_trip_id(current_user.id, @trip.id)
  redirect_to action: :edit, :id => @order.id  #need to update params here to reflect the order ID or address in edit action
end
end

def create
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
#Avoids saving line items that don't specify a quantity. A cleaner way to implement this probably exists.
@order.line_items.delete_if {|line_item| line_item.quantity.blank? || line_item.quantity == 0 }

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    UserMailer.send_invoice(current_user, @order, false).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    @trip = @order.trip
    @items = Item.find_all_by_destination_specific_activity_id(@trip.destination_specific_activity.id)
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Partial that generates the form of interest (some parts omitted for brevity)

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :trip_id, :value => @trip.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<% @items.each do |item| %> 
    <%= f.fields_for :line_items do |builder| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= builder.hidden_field :item_id, :value => item.id %>
            <%= builder.label item.name %>
            <%= builder.text_field :quantity, size: 2 %>
            <%= ' @ ' + number_to_currency(item.price) + ' each'%>
        </div>

    <% end %>   
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have searched on Stack Overflow and elsewhere for hours and can't figure out how to fix this. I assume that there is something going on under the hood in the form builder object, but that's as much as I can figure out. Please help!

Comment: I would probably need more specifics to provide an answer, but my guess is that `@order` is not what you expect it to be when `save` fails and you render it.  Can you update your OP with a dump of `@order` right before `@trip = @order.trip`, along with details of what is being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of seeking to understand the internals of FormBuilder, the answer was right in front of me the whole time. The problem is the `@items.each` loop in the partial. It loops through the FormBuilder object one time for each item. When `@order.line_items` is first initialized in the new action with `@order.line_items.build`, this adds one empty `LineItem` object to `@order.line_items.build`. The `@items.each` loop creates a set of `LineItem` fields for each `LineItem` in `@order.line_items`. When there is only 1 (empty) `LineItem` object in there, the fields appear correctly (i.e., 1 set of fields). However, when `@order.line_items` contains multiple `LineItem` objects (i.e., after a failed `@order.save` in the `create` action), `@order.line_items` contains multiple `LineItem` objects from the initial form submission, and the `@items.each` loop in the partial creates a set of fields for each `LineItem` object in `@order.line_items`.

A better way to solve this problem is to eliminate the `@items.each` loop in the partial. Instead, manipulate `@order.line_items` in the `create` action in the controller to include the proper and proper number of initialized `LineItem` objects. If a `LineItem` representing a given relevant Item was not included in the initial form submission, then a new initialized-but-otherwise-blank `LineItem` can be added to `@order.line_items`.